Ubuntu 24.10 with Gnome 47 sluggish when laptop unplugged
I noticed that when I disconnect my laptop from my power brick, Gnome tends to be very sluggish. Not the apps themselves but the desk itself. Touchpad cursor works but not as fluid as normal and windows animations seem to be a bit slower...
If I reboot the computer, while it is still unplugged, it's back to normal speed and efficience. So I tend to suspect a trouble with the power management when I unplug the computer...
I installed TLP in order to see if it gets things back to normal, but the same bug occurs. Each time I unplug the power cable from the computer, i get the same trouble so I have to reboot to get back to normal.
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ZenBook UX325EA_UX325EA
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            UX325EA.317
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               47
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.11.0-9-generic


AFAIK, I didn't have this trouble with Ubuntu 24.04.
